# Java multi-threads on array (split)

Tags: java, multithreading, matrix, split

I am looking for a solution to use an array in a Thread System (Master-Slave) which lets me divide calculations for a matrix on multiple threads via User Input and directs it through 1 main thread to several slave threads which calculate 1 field of the matrix.

I tried to use my knowledge but I am just transferring the problems in methods.
The code works, but only uses 1 Thread (after another) instead of all at the same time.

Thought I could divide the matrix somehow (is this a Spliterator?) but dont know how exactly.

ALso tried to use a boolean if the result field is empty but then it doesnt really work at all.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Threadverteiler extends Thread {

public Threadverteiler(Thread[] threads) {
    synchronisiert(threads);
}

public void synchronisiert(Thread[] t) {

    Thread[] threads = t;
    synchronized (threads) {
        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

            threads[i].start();
            System.out.println("Thread " + i + " gestartet");
        } // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    }

}

class Threads extends Thread {

    public Threads(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
        run(a, b);
    }

    /*
     * public Threadverteiler(Thread[] c, int[][] a,int[][]b) { //start();
     * run(a, b); //Arrays.spliterator(a);
     * //System.out.println(Arrays.spliterator(a));
     * 
     * }
     */

    public void run(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
        // synchronized (this) {

        // boolean arrayleer = false;

        // int[][]cc= new int[5][5];

        // public int[][] rechnen(int[][] a,int[][]b){

        // while( arrayleer==true){
        int[][] aa = new int[5][5];
        int[][] bb = new int[5][5];
        int[][] cc = new int[5][5];

        aa = a;
        bb = b;

        for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++)

        {

            for (int j = 0; j < bb.length; j++)

            {

                for (int k = 0; k < cc.length; k++)

                {

                    cc[i][j] = cc[i][j] + aa[i][k] * bb[k][j];
                    // cc[i][j] = cc[i][j] + a[i][k] * b[k][j];

                    /*
                     * if(cc[i][j]==0){ i++; j++; k++; continue; } else {
                     * System.out.println("Andere thread"); break;
                     * //arrayleer=false; }
                     */

                }

            }

        }

        /*
         * try { PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(new File());
         * 
         * } catch (Exception e) { // TODO: handle exception } return cc;
         * 
         * 
         * } }
         */

        // c=cc;
        // System.out.println("active Threads " + activeCount());

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(cc));
        System.out.println("active Threads " + activeCount());

    }

}

// }

public class Uebung2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[][] a = { { 1, -2, 3, 4, -1 }, { -2, 3, 0, 1, 2 }, { 4, -1, 2, 1, -2 }, { -2, 1, 3, -1, 3 },
                { 0, 2, -1, 2, 4 } };
        int[][] b = { { 2, -4, -1, 1, -2 }, { -1, 1, -2, 2, 1 }, { 5, 0, 3, -2, -4 }, { 1, -2, 1, 0, 2 },
                { 2, 3, -3, 0, 0 } };

        // int[][] c= new int[5][5];

        // System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
        // System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(b));

        // public static void threadauswahl(int x){

        // int i = 0;

        System.out.println("Bitte Anzahl Threads eingeben");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int eingabe = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[eingabe];

        // while (threads[i]==null) {

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Threads(a, b));

            // threads[i].start(); // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ändern!!
            // i++;
        }

        Threadverteiler s = new Threadverteiler(threads);

    }

}

// System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
// System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(b));
// System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(c));
```

Comment: You are calling the ``run`` method in the constructor of ``Threads``. Instead of only creating ``Threads`` instances, you already perform your work, then _afterwards_ try to run in in multiple threads. I suspect that's not what you want...

Comment: The way you have written this, every thread is repeating the same work. The hard part of this problem will be splitting the workload into distinct pieces that can be worked independently. Once you have a method that does an independent part of the problem, running it in parallel is easy.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, this design is already implemented in the API, via [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).  These will allow you a master (ExecutorService) to control a list of tasks, each containing a segment of your matrix, while the Futures report back upon completion.  You would still have to break up the matrix for each of the Future tasks, but should be trivial.

Comment: hmm seems what i was searching for but HOW can I split a matrix?
I thought thats a Spliterator (because of the name) but it seems only useable for primitive datatypes.

Comment: Yes, that's what Spliterator ("splitting iterator") is for.  The algorithm for splitting it is largely based on what you roughly expect the size of the matrix to be and how many worker threads you can conceivably have in your specific application while still maintaining acceptable performance and memory usage.  More than likely, the maximum number of threads you want will likely be the driver of how many times you call trySplit() on a very large collection.  That number can only be determined by you, for your application.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly, following should start multiple thread

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final int[][] a = { { 1, -2, 3, 4, -1 }, { -2, 3, 0, 1, 2 }, { 4, -1, 2, 1, -2 }, { -2, 1, 3, -1, 3 }, { 0, 2, -1, 2, 4 } };
        final int[][] b = { { 2, -4, -1, 1, -2 }, { -1, 1, -2, 2, 1 }, { 5, 0, 3, -2, -4 }, { 1, -2, 1, 0, 2 }, { 2, 3, -3, 0, 0 } };

        System.out.println("Bitte Anzahl Threads eingeben");

        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int eingabe = sc.nextInt();
        sc.close();

        final Thread[] threads = new Thread[eingabe];

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new Threads(a, b));
        }

        final Threadverteiler s = new Threadverteiler(threads);

    }

}

class Threadverteiler extends Thread {

    public Threadverteiler(final Thread[] threads) {
        synchronisiert(threads);
    }

    public void synchronisiert(final Thread[] t) {

        final Thread[] threads = t;
        synchronized (threads) {
            for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

                threads[i].start();
                System.out.println("Thread " + i + " gestartet");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
                try {
                    threads[i].join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

class Threads extends Thread {

    private final int[][] a;
    private final int[][] b;

    public Threads(final int[][] a, final int[][] b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int[][] aa = new int[5][5];
        int[][] bb = new int[5][5];
        final int[][] cc = new int[5][5];

        aa = a;
        bb = b;

        for (int i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bb.length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < cc.length; k++) {
                    cc[i][j] = cc[i][j] + aa[i][k] * bb[k][j];
                }

            }

        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(cc));
        System.out.println("active Threads " + activeCount());

    }

}
```